# FireFox cant establish a connection to the server at ws://1.1.1.26:81

Tags: java, php

I am new to Java and PHP, I am trying to add some features to the website, nut when i inspect the website i get this error. The website seems to work fine except for that it wont display variables i have in a config file. How do i get rid of this error? Here is my code for the websocket.

```
var FancyWebSocket = function(url)
{
    var callbacks = {};
    var ws_url = url;
    var conn;

this.bind = function(event_name, callback){
    callbacks[event_name] = callbacks[event_name] || [];
    callbacks[event_name].push(callback);
    return this;// chainable
};

this.send = function(event_name, event_data){
    console.log(event_data);
    this.conn.send( event_data );
    return this;
};

this.connect = function() {
    if ( typeof(MozWebSocket) == 'function' )
        this.conn = new MozWebSocket(url);
    else
        this.conn = new WebSocket(url);

    // dispatch to the right handlers
    this.conn.onmessage = function(evt){
        dispatch('message', evt.data);
    };

    this.conn.onclose = function(){dispatch('close',null)}
    this.conn.onopen = function(){dispatch('open',null)}
};

this.disconnect = function() {
    this.conn.close();
};

var dispatch = function(event_name, message){
    var chain = callbacks[event_name];
    if(typeof chain == 'undefined') return; // no callbacks for this event
    for(var i = 0; i < chain.length; i++){
        chain[i]( message )
    }
}
```

};

Comment: do you have a web sockets server running at 1.1.1.26:81?

Comment: I know this may sound dumb but how do i check that? I have a system that i am connecting to that has a windows based operating system. All the PHP and Java script files are on it. And when i type the address in on my computer it connects to that one. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Where does the web sockets code come from and why have you added it?